# Question on tensor product of von Neumann algebras and subfactors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be von Neumann algebras acting on Hilbert spaces $H_1,H_2$ and consider $M=M_1\overline\otimes M_2$ acting on $H_1\otimes H_2$. Let $K$ be an $M$-invariant subspace (so that $P_K\in M_1'\overline\otimes M_2'$).
Assume that $PMP = B(K)$.

Consider the von Neumann algebras $R_1 = P M_1\otimes 1 P $ and $R_2 = P1\otimes M_2 P$.
Then $R_1\vee R_2=B(K)$ and $R_1\subset R_2'$, so both $R_i$, $i=1,2$, are factors.
Therefore $R_1\subset R_2'$ is an irreducible subfactor inclusion.

My question is: Do I overlook something that already implies that $R_1 = R_2'$? If not, which irreducible subfactor inclusions can arise this way?

A more general question would be if normal *homomorphisms preserve relative commutants. This has surely been answered but I could not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you get $R_1 = R_2'$, and also $R_1 = B(K')$ for some $K'$.

1. The projection $P$ is minimal in $M_1' \mathbin{\bar\otimes} M_2'$:
   In general, if $M \subset B(H)$ is a von Neumann algebra and $P \in M'$ with range $K$, you have $(M P)' = P M' P$ on $K$.
   (You can find this in "Takesaki I", Proposition II.3.10.)
   From your assumption $M P = B(K)$, you get $P M' P = \mathbb C P$.
2. The algebras $M_i$ can be assumed to be type I factors:
   First look at the type (I, II, III) decomposition of $M_i'$.
   Use the fact that algebras of type II and III cannot contain minimal projections, and that the type I component of the tensor product $M'$ only comes from the type I components of $M_i'$.
   This reduces the situation to the type I case.
   Then you can further reduce it to the factor case by looking at the central support of $P$.
3. Now we know that $H_i = H_{i 1} \otimes H_{i 2}$ for $i = 1, 2$, with $M_i = B(H_{i 1}) \mathbin{\bar\otimes} \mathbb C$, $M_i' = \mathbb C \mathbin{\bar\otimes} B(H_{i 2})$, and $P$ is a rank $1$ projection on $H_{1 2} \otimes H_{2 2}$.
   Again from point 1 you get
   $$
   R_2' = P B(H_{1 1} \otimes H_{1 2} \otimes H_{2 2}) P = B(H_{1 1}) P = R_1.
   $$

Comment: Nice argument! thanks!